# Python: Nested for loop for 2D list error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: python

```
 def index_containing_substring(the_list, substring):
     for x, sublist in enumerate(the_list):
         for y, s in enumerate(sublist):
            if substring in s:
                return (x, y)
```

Error:

```
x,y = index_containing_substring(data,"PiID")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Do I need another return statement outside the loop? I tried return -1 and got TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I tried return -1,-1, but that would just return the same indicies regardless of the substring (even though the substring was definitely in the 2D list)

Comment: x,y = index_containing_substring(data,"PiID")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: If the condition is not satisfied the function will return `None` by default. You might want to do a `return None, None` instead (after the outer loop). Then the caller can check `if x is None`.

Comment: pi = data[x+1][y]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Of course you can't use a value for calculation if you don't have one.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't handling the case where the substring is not found.

```
l = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
s = 'dd'
x,y = index_containing_substring(l, s)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

You just have to return (None, None) at the end of the function for the case where it is not found.

```
def index_containing_substring(the_list, substring):
    for x, sublist in enumerate(the_list):
        for y, s in enumerate(sublist):
            if substring in s:
                return (x, y)
    return (None, None)
```

It would also be good practice to check the inputs to make sure they meet your expectations. (e.g. the_list is actually a list)